# Why does deciding the truth value of a statement in epistemic logic require fixing a set of possible worlds?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

In epistemic (modal) propositional logic, we have to set a collection of possible worlds in addition to the standard assignments of the predicate symbols to "true" or "false". However, the syntax does not require a set of possible worlds beforehand. For example, I can write...

$$K(\neg p\lor q)$$

...without having any knowledge about the possible worlds. Why can't I decide whether this is "valid" or "satisfiable" as in classical propositional logic without having to appeal to possible worlds semantics? Is there a formulation of epistemic logic semantics that doesn't involve appealing to some set of possible worlds?

Comment: In terms of syntax, the *satisfiability* of a propositional formula $\psi$ usually just refers to the fact that $\neg \psi$ is not provable in a given proof system. You can use any semantics that is sound and complete w.r.t. your proof system to show that a certain formula is not provable. Possible worlds semantics happens to be one such sound and complete semantics for epistemic logic. Nothing stops you from devising a new (e.g. algebraic) semantics for epistemic logic that does not involve possible worlds. However, there cannot be a sound/complete *two-valued* semantics for epistemic logic.

Comment: You have several questions in your post. 1) Why would we require possible worlds? This is a more philosophical question, and for some reasons and further pointers to relevant literature you can check out https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/#ModaApprKnow

Comment: 2)Can we do without possible worlds? Yes, we can. In a way, considering knowledge of an agent as what they have in their database is a bit more intuitive (at least from a computer science perspective). See, for example, Autoepistemic logic https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-nonmonotonic/#AutoLogi